# How to fill an array with a for loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, windows-8.1, winjs

I want to create a for loop that will generate a new element for `sampleItems` based on a fixed number set in a for loop.

```
var list = new WinJS.Binding.List();

var groupedItems = list.createGrouped(
  function groupKeySelector(item) { return item.group.key; },
  function groupDataSelector(item) { return item.group; }
);

generateSampleData().forEach(function (item) {
  list.push(item);
});

function generateSampleData() { 

  var sampleGroups = [
    { key: "group1", title: "Event1", backgroundImage: "/images/event1.jpg"}
  ];

  var sampleItems = [
    { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 1", content: "http://192.168.201.41/Stream" + [i] + ".mp4", backgroundImage: "/images/image1.jpg" }
  ];

  return sampleItems;
}
```

I tried to place a for loop within `sampleItems`  but i'm not allowed place the loop there.

Comment: what is `[i]` in the hash of `sampleItems`? Is it value that you assume you will have in for loop? :P

Comment: It would be useful if you provided the code for `for` loop you have tried to put into `sampleItems`.

Comment: `i` will be a value! I just want a basic for loop `var streams = 7 for(i=0; i<streams; i++)`

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863630/how-to-fill-an-array-with-a-for-loop-in-javascript/24864000#24864000

Comment: @KathyS As a good learner and contributor, if you found any answer useful, you should upvote for that

Comment: @RAJ...Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to upvote! very sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per conversation in question comments, here is the basic array population code for js:

```
var streams = 7;
var sampleItems = [];

for(i = 0; i < streams; i++) {
   sampleItems.push({'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'})
}
```

Replace `{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}` with desired key-value pairs

Answer (score 0):

Well you are looping over an array containing one object as entry. what you probably want to do is to discard you object structure completely and just use an simple array like:

var sampleItems = [ sampleGroups[0], "Item Title: 1", ..... ];

you could also make it a an actual object without using arrays but it seems to me that you want to use the `List`. If no `List` ist necessary just put the whole object genereated by
`generateSampleData` into you object or append it to an existing object.